# Are severe retinal haemorrhages proof of SBS?

Tags: medical-science

For years, certain classic retinal indicators have been considered absolute evidence of [shaken baby syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaken_baby_syndrome).  Doctors have made [explicit statements](http://dontshake.org/sbs.php?topNavID=3&subNavID=25&navID=278) that other activities like falls can't cause similar injuries (with a typical "well given infinite time" hedge). [other source](http://www.dontshake.org/sbs.php?topNavID=3&subNavID=25&navID=279)

Is it proven that the severe retinal haemorrhages can only be attributed to SBS?

Comment: What would "conclusive proof" look like? Surely, all that can be done is to eliminate all of the other *proposed* causes?

Comment: The [explicit statement](http://dontshake.org/sbs.php?topNavID=3&subNavID=25&navID=278) has 14 peer reviewed references...

Comment: There is an article in the latest issue of Private Eye on Shaken Baby Syndrome - http://www.private-eye.co.uk/sections.php?section_link=in_the_back&issue=1313

Comment: @Oddthinking -- Currently in american courts the present of the retinal hemorrhaging is accepted as prima-facie evidence of guilt if there was only one adult present when the trauma occurred.  However there are several new research papers (also peer reviewed) which challenge this and there have been several recent overturned convictions.

Comment: @Oddthinking -- One of the proposed "proofs" is to document a case where the same symptoms happened, but it is known that it could not possibly be from the baby being shaken... I've heard a lot on it and the recent articles have made me rather skeptical of the original research papers.  One counter example would be sufficient to prove that the retinal symptoms are not exclusive to SBS.

Comment: @RussellSteen: Agreed with your last comment. But that only allows answers in [one direction](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/777/untruthable-questions)

Comment: @Oddthinking -- I see your point (and I'm happy to take this to chat).  However, it's a legitimate claim, being made by scientists, that I'm skeptical of due to other recent research.  I'd like fix the question rather than remove it, and edit it to be more neutral.

Comment: As for the complaint about peer review: While clearly not all peer-reviewed articles are correct, we can't hope to be always correct. What we can do, however, is provisionally accept the most plausible model until counter-evidence comes along. Multiple peer-reviewed references provide a far more substantial reason to provisionally accept a statement than non-peer-reviewed ones. Reproduction is another powerful technique.

Comment: Crossed messages. I agree - important question. Editing it to be more neutral is perfect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3351/discussion-between-oddthinking-and-russell-steen)

Answer (score -1):

There is no disagreement among the mainstream medical community about the injury caused by Shaken Baby syndrome/Abusive head trauma which includes severe bleeding on the back surface of the eyes (retinal hemorrhages) identified by the current best evidence-based literature that reliably distinguish abusive injury from accidental [injury](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25316728). Retinal hemorrhages are [known](http://www.aafp.org/afp/2000/0515/p3057.html) to be highly suspicious for abuse resulting from Shaken Baby syndrome/Abusive head trauma.

> Published accounts of confessions document that some parents have shaken their children on repeated occasions, leading to the injuries that physicians identify in these cases. These reports confirm the published clinical [findings](https://www.aap.org/en-us/about-the-aap/aap-press-room/aap-press-room-media-center/Pages/Abusive-Head-Trauma-Fact-Sheet.aspx).

1. Several medical organizations such as the ones mentioned below have agreement about the injuries caused in Shaken Baby syndrome/Abusive head trauma found in children.

> The American Academy of Pediatrics, American Academy of Ophthalmology,
>   American Association for Pediatric Ophthalmology and Strabismus, American Academy of Family Physicians, American College of Surgeons, American Association of Neurological Surgeons, Pediatric Orthopaedic Society of North America, American College of Emergency Physicians, Canadian Paediatric Society, Royal College of Paediatrics and Child Health, Royal College of Radiologists, and American Academy of Neurology all recognize SBS/AHT as a form of infant abuse and have published position statements which describe their disciplines’ roles in its diagnosis and prevention. Both the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention of the U.S. Department of Health and Human Resources and the World Health Organization have similarly [published](http://dontshake.org/pdf/2015-03-23-WashPostResponse.pdf) position statements in support of the diagnosis of SBS/AHT.

2. There is also significant correlation between retinal hemorrhages with abusive head trauma suffered by the [babies](http://www.bcmj.org/articles/abusive-head-trauma-evolution-diagnosis). A [conclusion](http://www.epubs.utah.edu/index.php/ulr/article/view/1092/805) based on a systematic review of 320 studies resulting in inclusion of 14 studies involving 1,655 children that retinal hemorrhages and apnea had a high odds ratio and positive predictive value for inflicted brain injury.

> Numerous studies have documented the highly significant correlation of extensive, multilayered retinal hemorrhages with abusive head trauma, yet the exact mechanism of injury eludes us. Recent research creating finite element modeling of the infant eye confirms that rhythmic shaking significantly increases the stress on the retina. Further, the areas of greatest stress are found at the posterior pole and the peripheral retina, precisely where retinal hemorrhages are typically documented in cases of abusive head trauma.

3. The clinical features of Shaken Baby syndrome in Japan are also found to be comparable to those detailed in the Western medical literature for retinal haemorrhages through research which is found [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19763756) and [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23881041).
4. An evidence-based review in [2008](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19081701) found that 53-80% incidence of retinal haemorrhages with abusive head injury and a 0-10% incidence with proven severe accidental trauma.

> Studies found a 53-80% incidence of RH with abusive head injury and a 0-10% incidence with proven severe accidental trauma. RHs are found bilaterally 62.5-100% of the time in SBS cases, and flame-shaped hemorrhages are the most common. The incidence of RH from convulsions, chest compressions, forceful vomiting, and severe persistent coughing in the absence of another condition known to cause RH is 0.7%, 0-2.3%, 0%, and 0%, respectively.

5. A systematic review of literature from 1950 to 2009 found that certain patterns of retinal haemorrhages were very common in abusive head [trauma](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3545381/).

> Our systematic review confirms that although certain patterns of RH were far commoner in AHT, namely large numbers of RH in both the eyes, present in all layers of the retina, and extension into the periphery, there was no retinal sign that was unique to abusive injury. RH are rare in accidental trauma and, when present, are predominantly unilateral, few in number and in the posterior pole.

6. Research involving surviving/deceased victims, models of animals, mechanical [dummies](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24810668), and finite element analysis have demonstrated a pattern of vitreoretinal traction in the retinal hemorrhages suffered in [SBS](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4102172/).
7. A systematic meta-analytic review on the clinical and radiographic characteristics associated with abusive and nonabusive head trauma in 2012 found that retinal hemorrhages were significantly associated with abusive head trauma in [children](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22778309).

> In examining only studies deemed to be high quality, we found that subdural hemorrhage(s), cerebral ischemia, retinal hemorrhage(s), skull fracture(s) plus intracranial injury, metaphyseal fracture(s), long bone fracture(s), rib fracture(s), seizure(s), apnea, and no adequate history given were significantly associated with AHT.

Researchers however agree that there is difficulty in developing models that causes force replication required to cause retinal hemorrhage in [children](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20921069).

> Retinal hemorrhage is a cardinal manifestation of abusive head trauma. Over the 30 years since the recognition of this association, multiple streams of research, including clinical, postmortem, animal, mechanical, and finite element studies, have created a robust understanding of the clinical features, diagnostic importance, differential diagnosis, and pathophysiology of this finding. The importance of describing the hemorrhages adequately is paramount in ensuring accurate and complete differential diagnosis. Challenges remain in developing models that adequately replicate the forces required to cause retinal hemorrhage in children. Although questions, such as the effect of increased intracranial pressure, hypoxia, and impact, are still raised (particularly in court), clinicians can confidently rely on a large and solid evidence base when assessing the implications of retinal hemorrhage in children with concern of possible child abuse.